# How to use the ignore tag for ignoring tests from execution in the Concordion Specifications MD File

Tags: markdown, concordion

We are using concordion for Automation using Selenium webdriver. I have a list of tests in the MD File and I want to ignore few tests from execution. Is there any tag specific which can be mentioned in the Concordion specifications md file which can ignore the test which I would like to be ignored during execution.

Thanks
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

If using the Run command, you can add the JUnit @Ignore annotation to the test fixtures that are being executed by the run command. Note, this is likely to be replaced by a different mechanism as we implement a JUnit 5 runner.

Alternatively, within the specification, you can use the concordion-executeonlyif-extension to conditionally execute children. However, this is best suited to HTML format specifications and is difficult to implement with Markdown.